# Error: "Required Parameter is Missing" - While Getting Anonymous Table in BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am trying to query an anonymous table created as a result of querying a table dataset in BigQuery. I'm trying to use `Jobs.get()` to find the anonymous table name using the example in [Google BigQuery Analytics](http://pdf.th7.cn/down/files/1411/Google%20BigQuery%20Analytics.pdf) but I'm running into an error.

**Google BigQuery Analytics example** (page 209):

[image: Reference (Google BigQuery Analytics)]

**query 1:**

```
class QueryHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = discovery.build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
def query1(self):
    myquery = {'configuration': {
        'query': {
            'query': 'SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM `app.mydataset.mytable`',
            'destinationTable': {
            'projectId': projectId,
            'datasetId': datasetId,
            'tableId': 'tableId'},
            'useLegacySql': False
                 }
            }
    }

    response = service.jobs().query(projectId=projectId, body=myquery).execute()
    job = service.jobs().get(**response['jobReference']).execute()
    # both versions of this variable (destination_table) produce the same error message
    # destination_table = job['configuration']['query']['destinationTable']
    destination_table = job['destinationTable']

    table = service.jobs().get(projectId=destination_table['projectId'],
                              datasetId=destination_table['datasetId'],
                              tableId=destination_table['tableId']).execute()
    return table
```

**Error:**

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation.
>
> ....
>
> HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/app_id/queries?alt=json returned "Required parameter is missing">

***My Questions:***

1. Why am I getting this error? (I followed the example and I can't see what I missed)
2. How can I pass an *anonymous* table name from the first query in the second query using Python? For example:

**query 2:**

```
def query2(self):
....
query: SELECT * FROM [anonymous table from query 1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Why am I getting this error? (I followed the example and I can't see what I missed)

Your request body is malformed for the [`jobs.query` API call](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query).  You don't need the "configuration" or "query" object wrapping what you have there.

Try:

```
myquery = {
    'query': 'SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM `app.mydataset.mytable`',
    'useLegacySql': False
}

response = service.jobs().query(projectId=projectId, body=myquery).execute()
```

As a meta-comment, we (the BigQuery team) are aware that the "Required parameter is missing" error message is too vague to debug, and leads to confusing situations like this.  As well, unrecognized parameters (like the "configuration" object) are simply ignored, so if you name a parameter incorrectly in your request, you can very easily get the "Required parameter is missing" error.  We're hoping to resolve this issue in future API updates.

---

> 2. How can I pass an anonymous table name from the first query in the second query using Python?

You should be able to retrieve the destination table from a [`jobs.get` response](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get), presuming you pass in the expected `jobReference`.

However, note that using this anonymous table in another query is an [unsupported operation on anonymous results tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query), with no guarantees:

> The query results from this method are saved to a temporary table that is deleted approximately 24 hours after the query is run. You can read this results table by calling either bigquery.tabledata.list(table_reference) or bigquery.jobs.getQueryResults(job_reference). **The table and dataset name are non-standard, and cannot be used in any other APIs, as the behavior may be unpredictable.**

Instead, you are probably better off passing in an explicit destination table, which can only be done with [`jobs.insert`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert) and not with `jobs.query`.  Look for the parameter `configuration.query.destinationTable`.

You can put these destination tables in a dataset that [sets up an expiration time for contained tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/datasets#defaultTableExpirationMs) after a certain amount of time (an hour, or a day, or...) if you're concerned about keeping them around for a while.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to understand the BigQuery API documentation but unfortunately it's rather limited. I edited my code based on your suggestion for question 1 and it resolved the error.

Comment: Regarding using anonymous tables, I wouldn't use this method, however, I have 3 queries that take place back to back and they are dependent on the results saved to each table. `jobs.insert` wouldn't be a problem if it functioned in the same way as `jobs.query` but waiting for it to save to a permanent table, then querying the table presents its own challenges. If I run into issues, I'll rethink using `jobs.insert`. I think a cron job every 24 hours would work in dealing with anonymous tables. I'll see soon enough though. Thanks again.

Comment: Note that `jobs.query` is essentially doing the same operation as `jobs.insert`, but saving to a destination table with a system-generated name.  The main difference between the APIs is that query is a hanging request that returns when the job completes and jobs.insert starts an asynchronous job.  If you want similar behavior to `jobs.query`, you can consider using `jobs.insert` followed by a `jobs.getQueryResults`, as getQueryResults will wait for completion similarly to query.  More details in [our documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#running_asynchronous_queries).

Comment: Oh, that's definitely what I want to implement then. I did manage to get the anonymous tables working in my workaround but a permanent table that gets rewritten would use less code and no worries of weird behavior. :-) Great, I'll implement your recommendation asap. Thanks again.